# Getting axios posted data with a laravel request?

Tags: laravel, axios, laravel-5.5

I post data via axios:

```
axios.post('/api/test', {
      postId: 1,
      userId: 1,
})
```

Then on the Laravel backend I get the request via:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
....

public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());

}
```

But I get the error:

```
Uncaught ErrorException: Array to string conversion
```

I have dumped $request and the data does appear like so:

```
{"postId":1,"userId":1}
```

Comment: Please show how exactly are you using `$request->all()`

Comment: Have updated Laravel method

Comment: the code you've shown is ok. You're getting the error because somewhere you're trying to use an array as a string. Are you sure you've shown the whole method?

Comment: That is the entire method.

Comment: so, you're getting the error when it's completely empty? You've said you've added the `dd()` part after you got the error.

Comment: I think it's better to check your blade file , it's possible you are passing an array as string like this {{ $array }} this will cause an error because you can't echo an array.

Comment: Alexey Mezenin - it's never empty

Comment: BM2ilabs - this is not in a blade file.